# ORA-04091 and ORA-06512 ora_sqlcode: -4091 error while executing trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I tried to execute trigger its throwing many exceptions. Please suggest how this can be modified.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "WS5108"."AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG" AFTER
INSERT 
ON ITIB_REQUESTS FOR EACH row
DECLARE  
 V_CODE varchar(200);
BEGIN
IF :NEW."J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE" IS NULL THEN 

SELECT distinct (PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE) INTO V_CODE 
FROM ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE POC 
JOIN ITIB_VPDOMAIN VP ON (POC.VP_DOMAIN = VP.VP_DOMAIN) 
JOIN ITIB_REQUESTS ITIB ON (VP.ID = ITIB.VP_DOMAIN) 
WHERE VP.ID = :NEW."VP_DOMAIN" AND CAPEX_CATEGORY = :NEW."C_CAPEX_CATEGORY" ;
END IF;

UPDATE ITIB_REQUESTS SET  J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE = V_CODE;

EXCEPTION

when no_data_found then

  V_CODE := 0 ;

END;
```

Comment: You can't query the table that caused a trigger to fire inside the trigger itself.  You are using `ITIB_REQUESTS` in your query which is not accepted

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way that I can able to update this field after insert new row in this table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are few issues here. A good start would be to read AskTom about mutating error (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536903800346619276). I suppose it will give you a pretty good idea. Has a lot of examples as well.

Next, you're trying to update the same table during another update which causes the error. As this is the same table you could just do something like

```
:NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE := V_CODE;
```

Next is that this SELECT might return null recordset which is not handled (maybe the field is nullable?); or more than one record? An exception is not the best approach, because it is consuming resources heavily. The question is why you should insert something if there is missing data? Maybe MERGEing is better? Depends on many factors.

The other errors are probably resulting from the mutation error.